# rm -rf doesn't work for an empty directory

Tags: macos, command-line, unix

In terminal I try to delete a directory but that doesn't work:

```
myuser$ rm -rf foo/
rm: foo/: Directory not empty
```

In my main directory I have only foo :

```
myuser$ ls
foo
```

I haven't any problem with my 'ls -la' command:

```
myuser$ ls -la
drwxrwxrwx@ 1 myuser  staff  65536  1 mai 10:53 .
drwxrwxrwx@ 1 myuser  staff  32768 28 aoû  2013 ..
drwxrwxrwx  1 myuser  staff  32768  1 mai 10:36 foo
```

Directory foo seems to be empty :

```
myuser$ ls foo/

myuser$ ls -la foo/
ls:  : No such file or directory
total 192
drwxrwxrwx  1 myuser  staff  32768  1 mai 10:36 .
drwxrwxrwx@ 1 myuser  staff  65536  1 mai 10:53 ..
```

But the line "ls:  : No such file or directory" is weird. And I think it's the reason I can't delete this directory. 
We could see too, that "ls foo" return an empty line, like there is something, but what? And how delete it?

Thanks

Comment: Can you see the folder in the GUI? Can you cd into it?

Comment: Is that directory a mount point for something? Check with `df -h`. What's the output of `lsof foo`? Have you rebooted yet? Are there any encrypted files?

Comment: You could also run a filesystem check from Disk Utility.

Comment: Thank you for answers.
In fact this morning the directory have disappeared. So I can't test your different solutions.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the user no longer has the issue

Comment: @Oliver, how do you know the user no longer has the issue ? They haven't responded yet, and the original question/problem seems real enough; worthy of a question and answer surely ?

Comment: @Lqueryvg: He posted an answer (which should have been a comment or an edit), which was flagged and deleted.

Comment: Related: [Trying to delete directory with “rm -rf”, but get message that it's not empty](http://superuser.com/q/467059/87805)

Answer (score 2):

I reckon you might have a file in the `foo` directory with unprintable characters in it's name. Compare the characters you **see** in the `ls` output with the actual characters `ls` **outputs**.

```
cd foo
ls             # you see what your terminal lets you see
ls | od -a     # you see the character codes *really* coming from ls
```

There are various methods to help delete a file whose name you can't easily see or type.
Here you could use the interactive `-i` option of rm.

```
cd foo
rm -i *
```

Obviously, *be careful* with this. And only say `y` to the one you want to delete.

As to why your first `rm -rf` didn't delete it... I wonder if you have rm aliased? Use `alias rm` to see. You can temporarily run the real version of rm (bypassing the alias) using `\rm -rf foo`.

Answer (score 1):

The "Directory not empty" message is quite misleading. Normally, an `rm -rf` will remove everything in a directory, recursively, so it wouldn't matter if it's empty or not.

In this case, there are some things you might want to check:

- Try seeing if there's anything mounted in this directory with `df -h`, and unmount if necessary
- Try checking if there's a file open by an application, running `sudo lsof foo`, and quit the application(s) if necessary
- Try `sudo rm -rf foo` – perhaps you just don't have permissions (although I don't think that's the case here)
- Try logging out and back in
- Try rebooting the machine

Answer (score 0):

The command

```
 rm -rf dir
```

does not remove hidden files, *i.e.* those starting with a dot, like for instance *.bashrc*. The *directory not empty* diagnostic means you have some some hidden files, you may list them with either

```
 ls -a
```

or ith

```
 ls .*
```

You can erase them recursively with

```
 rm -rf .[a-Z]*
```

then you will be able to rmdir the offending directory.

EDIT:

The following Edit proves my point:

```
  root@rasal:/tmp# mkdir ttp
  root@rasal:/tmp# cd ttp
  root@rasal:/tmp/ttp# touch .test
  root@rasal:/tmp/ttp# ls -a
  .  ..  .test
  root@rasal:/tmp/ttp# rm -rf *
  root@rasal:/tmp/ttp# ls -a
  .  ..  .test
  root@rasal:/tmp/ttp#
```

Comment: That's wrong. `rm -rf dir` *does* remove hidden files in that directory. Try running `mkdir test && touch test/.foo && rm -rf test` as proof. The "directory not empty" error is a little misleading.

Comment: Sorry, @slhck, but this time you are wrong. Try: *mkdir ttp; cd ttp; touch .test;  ls -a; rm -rf *; ls -a* and you will discover that *.test* is still there. You owe me 2 points, thank you.

Comment: Your example shows something different – namely that the `*` glob does not include hidden files. Which is of course correct, but irrelevant to the question being asked, since there's no globbing involved. You said that "`rm -rf dir` will not remove hidden files", which is wrong, and which is what my example shows. `rm -rf dir` will delete all directory contents, regardless of whether they're dotfiles or not.