# rm Directory not empty

Tags: macos, bash

After booting my Mac into recovery mode I’m trying to run “rm -rf Mobile\ Documents” from “~/Library”.

But I’m getting a bunch of errors saying “Directory not empty”. I thought that “-r” would solve this problem. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: In recovery you don't have a ~/Library as you don't really have a user & you're not booted to the regular boot drive. Sounds like you're trying to delete something from the recovery image you're booted from.

Comment: @Tetsujin I mounted the drive using Disk Utility in Recovery Mode prior to running that command.

Comment: You still don't have a ~/Library, as you have no user. You'd probably need /Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/[me]/Library

Comment: @Tetsujin Yes sorry. That is what I meant. When I run “pwd” I get “/Volumes/Macintosh HD - Data/Users/charliefish/Library”

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to delete directory with "rm -rf", but get message that it's not empty](https://superuser.com/questions/467059/trying-to-delete-directory-with-rm-rf-but-get-message-that-its-not-empty)